# Ng-Repeat and Angular Filters

Tags: angularjs

I have an array of "action" objects. Each object has a status: "mastered" or "new".

On one nav-tab, I show the "new" actions:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in main.actions | filter: {status: '!mastered'} >

<div class="btn-group">
    <label ng-model="x.status" uib-btn-radio="'new'"><label>
    <label ng-model="x.status" uib-btn-radio="'mastered'"></label>
</div>

</div>
```

On a separate nav-tab, I show the mastered actions. My code there is identical with the exception of the filter included in the ng-repeat.

By clicking on these radio buttons, one can change the status of an action from "new" to "mastered." Everything works as intended, however, when I change the status of an action, the entire SPA returns to it's main page!

Why is that? What do I need to do to prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 0):

You can consolidate so you don't have to necessarily use a different tab for each status.Try something like this.

Code:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in main.actions | filter: {status: stat} "></div>


<div class="btn-group">
    <label ng-model="x.status" uib-btn-radio="'new'" ng-click="stat = 'new'"><label>
    <label ng-model="x.status" uib-btn-radio="'mastered'" ng-click="stat = 'mastered'"></label>
</div>
```

This should now filter your ng-repeat based on the button you click.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am not sure I follow, unfortunately. I do need to preserve the separation - there are actually 5 different statuses, and I need the "mastered" actions to be on their own tab. I want to preserve the ability to change the status of an action such that it can be moved from the main tab to the mastered tab.

Comment: The above code would still give you the affect of different tabs but it would keep your coding to  a minimum. If you insist on keeping them separate that is fine but you will need to provide more code then what you have provided above in order for someone to help further. Could you do that or create a jsFiddle with the problem.